# Failing with Adsense / How to get $ PC

Tags: google, wordpress, google-adsense

So, I am literally just starting out with google adsense. I have implemented google adsense ads from (1) account and from (2) different channels, per website they're on. (2 Wordpress Websites, activated with 'GoogleAdsense Plugin' for WordPress).

They are implemented at the bottom of every post on my 2 Wordpress websites within the 'Blog' sections. My adsense dashboard is stating I've received a few clicks; but across it still states my account earnings and balance at $0.00.

When / How will I start seeing money earned to my account?

Comment: Be specific. What is the actual time frame involved? "Just starting out" isn't anything to work with as far as telling you you're being impatient, etc. Similarly, "a few clicks" likely aren't worth much of anything anyway, but if it's a significant number and you see no earnings it might start indicating other problems(see @Anagio's comment below about invalidation).

Answer (score 4):

Google may have deemed those clicks invalid for any number of reasons. Another possibility is that the account is so new it hasn't registered the earnings.

Answer (score 0):

You need both great content and traffic for adsense revenues. Do you have either? If not, that 's your main concern and you should focus on that.